# Commerce Trying to get property 'abbreviation' of non-object

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, stripe

I am getting this error after payment. payment is successfully done not redirect. And getting this error **Trying to get property 'abbreviation' of non-object**. I don't know why i am getting this error or what cause this error
[image]

Comment: What version of Craft and Commerce is this? Can you edit the question and share the full stack trace leading up to the error from the Craft `storage/logs` folder?

Comment: Thank for your response issue is solved. custom plugin cause the error.

Comment: Glad you're all sorted, @Taher - want to add that as an official answer?

Comment: Yeah sure @BradBell